# use Storyboard and xib for same viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have been using storyboard in this project of mine. Except 3.5 inch iphone screen other ipad and iphone designs fixed. In 3.5 inch button overlapping, view hiding is not fixed. Is this possible to load xib for iPhone 3.5 inch screen for other screen loads using storyboard?

Comment: by setting up your elements constraints to fit any kind of screen size.

Comment: use different ways...hide some view or button overlapping or bottom view hide any one occurs in using constraints for 3.5 inch size.other sizes work perfectly

Comment: if you are set constraint perfectly to view in storyboard then it works in all device. why you are increasing your work to making two UI files for single view.

Answer (score 0):

To get the screensize you can use `UIScreen`

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

Then with some `if`statments you should be able to do adjustments depending on your screensize.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can do that by simple if condition

```
UIViewController *viewController
if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height==480)
{
      viewController=[[viewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"your_nib_name" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
       viewController = [self.storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your_vc_id"];
}
```